# Tableview images chaging when scrolling using custom tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a Tableview and i am using the customTableview cell for displaying the cell

in the cell i have 5 buttons (rating buttons) when i click on particular button the image of the button has to changed its working fine but when i am scrolling the tableview again thay are changing to normal rating buttons see the following images for clarity

This is the image before scrolling and clicking nothing on button

[image: This is the image before scrolling and clicking nothing on button]

after  clicking the on rating buttons the image is changing like this

[image]

but when scrolling the cells again its changing to first image

please help me out

Code :

```
- (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    dataCell = (DataCel)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (dataCell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DataCel" owner:self options:nil]; dataCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return dataCell;
}
```

Comment: show your code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You need to remember/store state of cell's data and fill up again !

Comment: i have nothing done in the CellForRowAtIndexPath

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    dataCell = (DataCel*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (dataCell==nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DataCel" owner:self options:nil];
        dataCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return dataCell;
}

Answer (score 1):

you should save the sate of the button images
and in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

insert  code to keep them updated
for ex:

```
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
//create your cell here if it was not created 
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        }

        NSArray *array = [imageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        if([[array objectAtIndex:3] isEqual:@"rate3"])
        {
            //set the code for the rating 3
        }
        else
        {
            //insert another rate depending on your object
        }
```

Comment: When click on the particular rate button it will not goto didselect row at indexpath beacause i am clicking on button directly so how can i get the cell indexpath

Comment: isn't the button inside your cell?

Comment: when you create your button in cellForRow , set the tag of the button for the current row
button.tag=[indexPath row];

In your receiver , type the following
- (void)setState:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender tag %d",[sender tag]);
//this will be your current row of the button clicked
//you can retrieve the current indexPath using 
NSIndexPath* indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag]  inSection:0];
}

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time you scroll the `UITableView`, it refreshes its values from the data you provided it ! So the value is not retained. To prevent this from happening every time you scroll the database you can use this

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
}

for(id obj in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] || [obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        [obj removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This would not let the values be overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

When scrolled the cells are recreated and so you need the keep the selected values in a seperate array and set it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every time you scroll the tableview , it re-create tableview cell. therefor you can use array for reused it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *cellId = @"cellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [categoriesTableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];

    }
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

// ui goes here

return cell
}
```