# Swift handle Play/Pause button inTableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement play/pause button in tableview cell. each cell having single button, whenever user click it, It should change button image also need to call required function, also after scroll it should same.

Below code I am using

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productCell") as ? SepetCell
    cell.onButtonTapped = {
       //Do whatever you want to do when the button is tapped here
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See first of all every button of the tableView Cell will have a unique tag associated with it, so in order to update the button of a particular cell, you will have to define the tag of a button in the cells and then pass this tag to your function to perform action on that particular button of the selected cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_identifier", for: 
         indexPath) as! CellClass
      cell.button.tag  = indexPath.row
      cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playpause), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
  @objc func playpause(btn : UIButton){
       if btn.currentImage == UIImage(named: "Play") {
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named : "Pause"), forState: .Normal)
     }
      else {
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named : "Play"), forState: .Normal)
     }
   // perform your desired action of the button over here
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Samarth Kejriwal, btw I am getting error in play pause function 'Normal' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set

Comment: use `.normal` to set the control-state of button in Swift3

Comment: Thanks you so much. one more doubt I didn't set tag right so whenever tableview cell reused have a chance to change the button state automatically am I right? Can you please tell one more solution for this?@samarth Kejriwal

Comment: when I scroll tableview cell, listed button image will have a chance to change automatically or not. Like this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515183/tableview-images-chaging-when-scrolling-using-custom-tableview

Comment: No the listed button will not change the button image automatically because you have passed the button tag in your action and that particular button image is updated, it won't change automatically on scrolling

Comment: Great.Thank You @Samarth Kejriwal

Answer (score 1):

State of the art in Swift are callback closures. They are easy to implement and very efficient.

In the data source model add a property

```
var isPlaying = false
```

In Interface Builder select the button in the custom cell and press <kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd> to go to the Attributes Inspector. In the popup menu `State Config` select `Default` and choose the appropriate image from `Image` popup, Do the same for the `Selected` state.

In the custom cell add a callback property and an outlet and action for the button (connect both to the button). The image is set via the `isSelected` property.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button : UIButton!

var callback : (()->())?

@IBAction func push(_ sender: UIButton) {
    callback?()
}
```

In the controller in `cellForRow` add the callback, `item` is the current item of the data source array. The state of the button is kept in `isPlaying`

```
cell.button.isSelected = item.isPlaying
cell.callback = {
    item.isPlaying = !item.isPlaying
    cell.button.isSelected = item.isPlaying
}
```